# What is the meaning of 'the model generates the video on a frame-by-frame basis'?

Tags: audio, video

I'm reading a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.02966), and in the paragraph describing the model it says,

> The model generates the video on a frame-by-frame basis by sliding a 0.35-s window over the audio sequence. The frame is moved forward by 1 frame (0.04 s) at a time.

This model generates a video of a talking face given two inputs: (1) an audio segment, (2) still images of the target identity(frontal headshot).

And the quoted part is confusing.

For example, if input is an audio of 1.4 seconds long, the model generates the video of 4 frames, right?

But the frame is moved forward by 1 frame at a time, so it's 0.16 seconds long.

Then it means 1.4 seconds long audio became 0.16 seconds long video.

Where did I get lost?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe the confusion is that the frame rate of a video will not necessarily exactly divide into the video time.

For example if you had a frame rate of 2 frames per second and a 10 second long video then it's clear that it stops on the 20th or last frame at 10 seconds exactly.

If your video was just 9.45 seconds long then the video stops on whatever was the last frame - in this case the one at 9.30 seconds.

Comment: Okay, so let’s say 3.5 seconds long audio is the input, then 3.5 seconds long video should be the output, and then 3.5 * 25(25 frames for a second) will be needed..But then where we use the 0.35 s window? No difference whether we use 0.35 s window or 0.5 s window if everything is determined by the length of frame.